# How to redirect to an MVC page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have currently got a MVC application that redirects to another website:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //create instance of class to get info
        FreeAgentInfo info = new FreeAgentInfo();

        //Create Url and redirect
        string url = string.Format(@"{0}/v{1}/approve_app?&redirect_uri={3}&response_type=code&client_id={2}", info.BaseUrl, info.Version, info.ApiKey, info.Callback);
        return Redirect(url);
    }
```

This will send the application to another website but when its finsihed it needs to return to the MVC app. This is done by providing a callback url for it to redirect to. 
The callback needs to a link to a page on my MVC app

For example I also have this action:

```
public ActionResult Invoices()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Its location is "~/Views/Home/Invoices.cshtml" and its running off the localhost

What should I use as the callback url to get it to return to this page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the Url helper to generate an absolute url for the callback that you would pass to the external website:

```
string callback = Url.Action("Invoices", "MyController", null, Request.Url.Scheme);
```

and then pass this callback:

```
string url = string.Format(
    @"{0}/v{1}/approve_app?&redirect_uri={3}&response_type=code&client_id={2}", 
    info.BaseUrl, 
    info.Version, 
    info.ApiKey, 
    callback
);
return Redirect(url);
```

By using the Url helper it is guaranteed that this will always generate a valid url to your controller action no matter what routes you have configured. Also if you change your routes one day, you don't need to remember that you had some custom code calculating this callback when calling the external website.

So never hardcode urls in an ASP.NET MVC application. Always use url helpers when dealing with them.

Comment: I wanted to keep all the information related to this in the separate class, which doesnt accept the .Action - Its a good solution and more secure than mine though

Comment: In this case simply have this class take as parameter an UrlHelper that you would pass from your controller action. Since this class is dealing with urls it would make perfect sense to have dependency on an url helper. Otherwise I don't even want to think what you are doing inside.

Comment: Ive implemented your url helper solution, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, I was adding "/Views/" to the url.

```
"http://localhost:52006/Home/Invoices"
```

Thats the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to emphasise RedirectToAction() tells MVC to redirect to specified action instead of rendering HTML, it acts like a Response.Redirect() in ASP.NET WebForm.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string Name)
{
   ViewBag.Message = "Hello Word";
   //Like Server.Transfer() in Asp.Net WebForm
   return View("MyIndex");
}

public ActionResult MyIndex()
{
  ViewBag.Msg = ViewBag.Message; // Assigned value : "Hello World"
  return View("MyIndex");
 }
```

Hope this clarifies the situation.